# Parallel Stripes and the classic globe confirmation experiment

Tags: earth, home-experiment, thought-experiment

I have been taking time this summer to try and understand what "reasons" some flat earthers offer for their beliefs for a "science and the public" class. One of the oldest and most obvious observations that proves a sphere-like earth is the "sinking ship." In order to verify this observation,  modern experiments (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06bvdFK3vVU)) use a boat with parallel Strips on the mast.

Flat earthers sometimes [argue](https://wiki.tfes.org/Sinking_Ship_Effect_Caused_by_Limits_to_Optical_Resolution) that it is the "vanishing point effect" that results in the hull appearing to sink before the upperparts and they claim (without authentic confirmation) incidents of "recovering" half-sunken ships by zooming in. In order to refute this contention, I reasoned that the parallel, equally spaced strips are useful (I did not have personal access to a seashore). As far as I understand the [vanishing point effect](https://iveabout.com/vanishing-point-drawing-definition-1123080#:%7E:text=A%20vanishing%20point%2C%20or%20point,have%20a%20three-dimensional%20look.), it is that when we observe parallel lines moving away from us, they seem to move closer and eventually meet at a point. So one can imagine a "water line" and a "hull line" both parallel, and as the ship moves away, the lines seem to meet. But in the experiment with stripes, the upper pairs of stripes still appear far apart as the lower ones appear to sink, ruling out the possibility that the disappearing of the lower stripes "into the water" is caused by this vanishing point effect. Ergo, zooming in can not recover a half sunken ship.

I wanted to know whether this explanation is physically sound.

Comment: As a practical experiment, the results from this can be confused by the mirage effect caused by temperature gradients in the air above the water surface. This can made medium sized ships (i.e. say 5,000 to 10,000 tons DWT) "appear and disappear" randomly when they are several miles offshore. A better controlled experiment might be to use different colored lights at different heights up the mast, and make the observations at night when the air is more stable.

Comment: there are other simple and strong demonstrations of the earth-as-sphere we could furnish. would you be willing to consider them? -Niels

Comment: @niels, yes sure. But I would also like to know about this one (both a course requirement and out of interest). Basically I think their own principle of vanishing point suggests that you cant zoom into to recover the hull since usually when we see boats "sink" , the mast part is still very much normal( as opposed to what their theory predicts ). Could I discuss these in chat so I dont have to make a new question?

Answer (score 1):

As alephzero pointed out, the "sinking boat" demonstration will be affected by temperature gradients right next to the water surface, which themselves will bend light rays that happen to make grazing angle contact with the water.

This does not refute the spherical earth argument, as this effect has been known and understood for hundreds of years. It just means that it is possible for flat-earthers to cherry-pick evidence to the contrary.

The vanishing-point effect does not geometrically support the flat earth hypothesis nor does it refute the idea of a spherical earth. This is because the ship disappears below the horizon before the vanishing point effect shrinks it apparent length to zero.

Using a mast with lights on it, as suggested by Sal_99, would make the effect easier to measure- as would using the tallest mast available. In fact, why use a mast at all? A captive balloon with a very long string of powerful lights or radar retro-reflectors would be better- and would allow the effect to be more powerfully demonstrated.

As an aside, the invention of accurate surveying instruments (used to lay out straight property lines and the like) demonstrated over 150 years ago that the earth was not flat. By setting up a square line layout on the surface of the earth, you will find that if the lines are very accurately "shot" at exactly 90 degrees at the corners, the lines will fail to "close" in the right place, proving that the earth is bulged up inside the big square, and that the size of this effect is the same all around the world.

Of course, if the survey team tries to lay out a really big square that has a portion of the equator for one side and two other sides that both point exactly north, they will discover those lines intersecting at the north pole, which they would assuredly *not* do if the earth were flat.

Finally, note that the belief in a flat earth is a religion, and no amount of geometric, mathematical or logical reasoning will undo that belief.